# What code do I use to send a NotesURL for a document in a view?

Tags: lotus-notes

While I know that I can use the UNID of the document to open the document directly from a link referencing Notes, can it be done with the view name and first column value as in the browser?

For example, I could send:

```
http://mycompany.com/OpsManual.nsf/Policy/6
```

To get to Policy #6 in the Operations Manual via the browser client. I thought that I could send:

```
Notes://mycompany.com/OpsManual.nsf/Policy/6
```

To send them to the same place in the Notes client, but it always opens to the default Notes opening setting. Is there a form, database or server setting that I have wrong? Or am I mis-remembering how NotesURLs work? Can you only use the NotesURL in LotusScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Notes URL syntax is

```
notes://servername/database/view/documentuniqueid
```

You can omit the documentuniqueID and just include the viewID, but you can't specify a row, or jump to a certain row based on its value in a column.

Answer (score 1):

You need the OpenDocumentByKey parameter to do that, but unfortunately that only works in a web browser, not in the client - so this won't work :-(

```
Notes://mycompany.com/OpsManual.nsf/Policy/6?OpenDocumentByKey
```

Alternatively, you can write a bit of LotusScript or formula to find the UNID of the document, and then use that.  For example:

```
docUNID: = @DbLookup("":"" ; "":"" ; "Policy"; policyNumber; 1; [RETURNDOCUMENTUNIQUEID]);
"Notes://mycompany.com/OpsManual.nsf/Policy/" + docUNID
```

Comment: Actually, in the browser, you don't need the OpenDocumentByKey. It works without it.

Comment: I ended up created a column with @Text(@DocumentUniqueID) as the formula and using the DbLookup to find that value to provide a computed URL in a hotspot on a page. Works like a charm. Thanks for guiding me toward that, Phil!

Comment: You're welcome, David.  And thanks for letting me know about not needing OpenDocumentByKey.  All my development is for client, so it's not my area of expertise!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to (manually) generate a Notes:// URL is to get a document- or view- or application-link selecting one of those things in the Notes client, and choosing *Edit → Copy As → ...*, and then pasting the link into a Sametime chat session.  Instead of the icon link you'd get if you pasted it into (e.g.) a Notes e-mail message, you get a URL.

If you need to generate the URL programmatically, doing it manually first the way I describe gives you the structure as a starting point.

Also (potentially) useful is pasting the link into a text editor, as it describes the structure for you in XML (or at least an XML-like format).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the notes-url documentation in the Lotus Notes & Domino wiki from IBM: 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/notes-urls

As far as I know the view can either be specified by UNID or NoteID.

Answer (score 0):

Notes:///DbReplicaId/viewUnid/YourKeyHere?OpenDocumentByKey

This works for me using LN 8.5